# PowerShell to remove matching line plus immediately following line

Tags: powershell-5.0

I am trying to convert a “sed” script I use on my FreeBSD machine to one using “Powershell” on Windows 10.

This is the sed script. It is used to strip a header from an email plus the immediately following line and send the output to “email_1.txt”. The file is fed to the script on the command line; i.e. “COMMAND file”

```
sed '/Received: by 2002:a17:90a:3566:0:0:0:0/,/^/d' <$1> email_1.txt
```

I cannot find a way to get this to work with “PowerShell”.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. Install sed -
   Something like [scoop](https://scoop.sh/) might be helpful here.
2. Write a pure powershell solution.
   This will be very similar to what you would write if you were to try to do the same thing in "pure" bash. Here is an attempt to do so:

--

```
function Delete-TargetLines {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [String]$needle,

        [int]$count = [int]1,

        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$haystack
    )

    Begin {
        [int]$seen = 0
    }

    Process {
        if ($seen -gt 0) {
            $seen -= 1
        } elseif ( $haystack -match $needle ) {
            $seen = 1
        } else {
            $haystack
        }
    }
}
```

And an example of running it:

```
> @("Pre-line", "This is a test", "second line", "post line") | Delete-TargetLines -needle "test"
Pre-line
post line

> Get-Content $myfile | Delete-TargetLines -needle 'value' > $outfile
```